# VirtualKeyboard not Show when focus Edit fields in Firemonkey project

Tags: focus, edit, firemonkey, virtual-keyboard, delphi-10-seattle

I have a Firemonkey multi device project in Delphi 10 Seattle where the user can get a screen at the start of the app. Here the user needs to fill in 2 fields. But when I click on the edit fields the Virtual Keyboard isn't shown. If I skip this screen at start and call it later then the Virtual Keyboard is shown. This is done in the same way too.

I found sort of a solution:
When i click on the edit fields i call show VirtualKeyboard myself. The only problem is that the cursor isn't shown in the edit field.

Is there a way to place the cursor myself? Or does anyone know how to solve the Virtual Keyboard not showing problem in an other way?

Problem is on both Android and iOS

In the code below you can see the initial form create. The problem is when in ConnectFromProfile method the actCreateNewProfileExecute is called. There it will call a new form. In that form(TfrmProfile) the virtual keyboard isn't shown. I also call this form with another action and then it works fine.

```
procedure TfrmNocoreDKS.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Inherited;
  System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';
  CheckPhone;
  ConnectfromProfile;
  if not Assigned(fProfileAction) then
    ConnectDatabase
  Else
    lstDocuments.Enabled := False;

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  ChangeComboBoxStyle;
{$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TfrmNocoreDKS.ConnectfromProfile;
begin
  fdmProfileConnection := TdmConnection.Create(nil);
  fdmProfileConnection.OpenProfileDb;
  fdmProfileConnection.LoadProfiles;

  if fdmProfileConnection.Profiles.Count = 0 then
  begin // Createdefault Profile
    fProfileAction := actCreateNewProfileExecute;
  end
  else if fdmProfileConnection.Profiles.Count = 1 then
  begin // one profile load connection;
    fProfileAction := nil;
    fCurrentProfile := fdmProfileConnection.Profiles.Items[0];
  end
  else
  begin // multiple profiles choose connection;
    fProfileAction := SelectProfileOnStartUp;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmNocoreDKS.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(fProfileAction) then
    fProfileAction(Self);
end;

procedure TfrmNocoreDKS.actCreateNewProfileExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  profilename, databasename, pathname: string;
  prf: TfrmProfile;
begin
  prf := TfrmProfile.Create(nil);
  prf.Data := fdmProfileConnection.Profiles;
  prf.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if ModalResult = mrOk then
      begin
        profilename := prf.edtProfilename.Text;
        databasename := prf.edtDatabaseName.Text;

{$IFDEF IOS}
        pathname := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
        pathname := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF WIN32}
        pathname := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '\Data';
{$ENDIF}
        FDSQLiteBackup1.Database := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(pathname,
          'default.sqlite3'); // Default Database
        FDSQLiteBackup1.DestDatabase := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(pathname,
          databasename + '.sqlite3');
        FDSQLiteBackup1.Backup;
        fdmProfileConnection.AddProfile(databasename + '.sqlite3', profilename);
        fdmProfileConnection.LoadProfiles;
        fCurrentProfile := fdmProfileConnection.Profiles.Items[0];
        connectDatabase;
      end else
        Application.Terminate;
    end);
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'get a screen at the start of the app'? Is it a form or is it a dialog?

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov it's a form. But it's not always shown. It depends on certain conditions.

Comment: @Remi please, show your .dpr code (I think, a login form is shown there(?)) and specify target platform.

Comment: @kami i've updated my question. Also with .dpr but i don't think this wil help.

Comment: @Remi Well, it really didn't help. Initially I thought that problem form shown in dpr... But now we know, what this form shows in code TfrmNocoreDKS (?). Please, remove `uses` section, it is not necessary, and add code to reproduce this behavior. I mean code, where problem form created and shown.

Comment: @kami I've added code

Comment: Where is fProfileAction executed?

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov in FormShow. I've added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not show any additional forms in `MainForm.OnCreate/OnShow`. Trying this on iOS 9.2 freeze app at "launch screen".

Instead of this, show new form asynchronously, like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTask.Run(procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure // work with visual controls - only throught Synchronize or Queue
        begin
          Form5:=TForm5.Create(Application);
          Form5.ShowModal;
        end)
    end);
end;
```

of cource, you can separate this code to external procedures:

```pascal
procedure ShowMyForm;
begin
  Form5:=TForm5.Create(Application);
  Form5.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TaskProc;
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, ShowMyForm);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTask.Run(TaskProc);
end;
```

========

Another way - do not use any additional forms. Create frame and put it (at runtime) on MainForm with `Align = Contents`. After all needed actions - hide or release (due to ARC dont forget to set nil to frame variable) this frame.

Comment: After moving code from onFormShow to onFormActivate the problem was solved. Thanks to your tip!

Comment: @Remi. Imho, move code to OnActivate is not good solution. You can enter to infinite loop: second form closed -> main form automatically activated ->second form showed. And again, and again.This solution will require much more attention of the developer

Comment: no that's not possible. I've added a check if it's on startup.

Comment: Should point out that ShowModal doesn't work for Android.