# Showmessage in formhide causing issue in custom styles, firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to show a message box in my form's hide event in delphi xe5 firemonkey form.
when i am doing so, all my custom styles are getting corrupt when the box is shown. Same problem is there if i use showmodal rather then using showmessage.

Any solution for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311346/4908529  ?

Comment: Above suggestion is not working for me. It seems like my form is getting zoom in/out effect when it is happening...

Comment: Please, provide an [**mcve**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In a quick test I could not reproduce the problem.