# Delphi - TEdit does not show cursor if form created from project by method

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

If I create a Method like below:

```
function Login : boolean;
begin
  with TMyForm.Create(Application) do
    Result := ShowModal = mrOk;
end;
```

in dpr

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  if Login then
  begin
    Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
    Application.Run;
  end
  else
    Application.Terminate;
end.
```

cursor on MyForm's TEdit control does not show but it has focus. But if I call same Login method from elsewhere cursor is view able. Why it's happening and how to solve it.

Below is my code:

```
unit Unit16;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit;

type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

function Login : boolean;

var
  MyForm: TMyForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

function Login : boolean;
begin
  with TMyForm.Create(Application) do
  begin
    Result := Showmodal = mrOk;
  end;
end;

end.
```

and my program code:

```
program Project14;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit15 in 'Unit15.pas' {Form15} ,
  Unit16 in 'Unit16.pas' {MyForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  if Login then
  begin
    Application.CreateForm(TForm15, Form15);
    Application.Run;
  end
  else
    Application.Terminate;

end.
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. You are calling the `Login` function from `dpr`, creating the `TMyForm` instance and then, if user clicks OK, you create another `TMyForm` instance? I think you need to review your logic.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Search this site for **[delphi] create login form** (that exact phrase, including the part in brackets).

Comment: Maybe the TEdit does not get the focus. But that's just a guess on your incomplete question.

Comment: It's a mistake on creating TMyForm, sorry. It should be TMainForm instead TMyForm in the dpr. TEdit does get focus but does not show cursor.

Comment: I don't understand why you won't show your code. How can you expect us to help?

Comment: This is the full code. I just want to know why cursor is not view able when Login method is calling from DPR. There is no other code.

Comment: Well, no it is not the full code. There are two forms whose code we cannot see. There's the .fmx file. I never understand why people fight it when we ask to see the code. Please show a [mcve]. I guess you don't understand what that means. Please follow the link to find out.

Comment: Please see my code as I told it's a simple.

Comment: Form15 is totally empty form.

Comment: @KenWhite search by tag [delphi] is not enought, because all answers contains VCL code, which doesn't work in FMX, especially in Android. Search by tag [firemonkey] give one answer, proposing a not good algorithm.

Comment: I reproduced the error. I think, this is general limit of Firemomkey platform. For possible workaround, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/35272757/4908529

Comment: @kami: It still shows the proper way to create a login form in the DPR and code, regardless of whether it's VCL or FMX. The code here is not correct. Also, look at the revision history - when I posted that link, the post had far different content than it does now.

Comment: kami I tried your workaround but it activate both Login form and Main form at the same. It's not workable. I have to do it in Windows and Mac OSX. This is what receive in Embarcadero Discussion forum https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=176371&tstart=0 please see it. Either way it's not good solution. From program execution is good where VCL can do it but not FMX.

Comment: @shariful for Embarcadero forum, please note phrase `message processing is done in the Application.Run` and  `You can assign MainForm as the mainform by calling Application.MainForm:=MainForm;`. I believe that this is the only way to solve the problem. For Windows you also you can set `Edit.ControlType` to `Platform` to show cursor, but you lose style of Edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into the same problem in C++ Builder. The problem seems to be that ApplicationState() must return TApplicationState.Running for the cursor to be shown. ApplicationState() returns Running when Application.FRunning is true. Application.FRunning is set to true in Application.Run().

I have added the following code to my project, which replaces ApplicationState() with one that always returns Running. I don't know how you do that in Delphi though.

```
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE TApplicationState __fastcall Fmx::Forms::ApplicationState(void)
{
   return TApplicationState::Running;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert and I don't know if this was resolved, but I came across the exact same problem so I thought I would share my solution.

I found that adding MainForm.Activate did the trick. I'm not sure why, but Application.Run seemed to override it, so MainForm.Activate has to be called AFTER Application.Run.

I did this by putting MainForm.Activate in the TMainForm.FormFocusChanged event.

To make this more efficient, you could even use a public Boolean variable and an if-statement to make sure that MainForm.Activate is only called once (that is, the first time TMainForm.FormFocusChanged is called).

Not the cleanest solution but it's the only thing that worked for me.